# SOQL Relationship name?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, relationships

Case Object has a lookup relationship to 
Parent_Project_if_applicable__c

The relationship name is Cases1.

I receive the error message:

```
Line: 15, Column: 28Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Cases1__r.Implementation_status__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:38 Didn't understand relationship 'Cases1__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

My code

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                         FROM Case
                                         WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 
                                         GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                         HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 1];

                         Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();
                for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){

                    Id accId = (Id)aggr.get('AccountId');
                        AcctIds.add(accId);
                }


                List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name,  Cases1__r.Implementation_status__c,
                Cases1__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];

            //System.debug('This is CaseList ' + caseList);


            for(Case cl:caseList){ 

             //   System.debug('Implementation Status: ' + (String)cl.get('Cases1__r.Implementation_status__c'));
               // System.debug('cl: '+ cl);


            }
```

[image: Case Object]

[image: Here is the Parent_Project_if_applicable__c]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

You've added a lookup field on the Case object. Creating a lookup field is always done on the child object.

Looking at the documentation provided above, you can see the difference in how you go about the relationship in SOQL (child-to-parent vs. parent-to-child).

[image]

To figure out your relationship name, I'd use workbench. Select Info --> Standard & Custom Object. Select Your "Case" object. Go into the custom object under fields (Mileston1_Project__c, select it, and then note the relationship name). Use this with __r appended as shown below.

[image]

```
List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Milestone1_Project__r.Implementation_status__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId in: AcctIds];
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how this type of join works. You need to include a *subquery* using that name in its `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT Fields__c, (SELECT SubFields__c FROM Children__r) FROM MyObject__c
```

Always double check the Relationship Name programmatically. I find this habit to be the most reliable way to obtain it:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Parent__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == Child__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100540/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-soql-relationship-name).